# Schematic modification

Tags: amplifier, biasing

I am trying to design a PCB for the biasing circuit. I found this [application note](https://www.integratech.com/resources/application-note-004.pdf) from integratech.

As you can see in the application note, it has input detection circuit and SPST circuitry.

I need manual applying of the gate and drain voltage. Is it possible to remove unwanted circuitry and keep the rest?

I have indicated the circuitry I am planning to remove in a black square. I have also indicated the connection I will be making between voltage inverter and amplifier in the red colour line.

I am designing biasing circuit PCB fro this power amplifier:- [CGH40120F](https://www.wolfspeed.com/downloads/dl/file/id/399/product/122/cgh40120f.pdf)

[image]

Comment: It's not obvious what your PCB is being designed to do.

Comment: @Andyaka I am designing biasing circuit for driving CGH40120F Power amplifier

Comment: Why don't you use what the data sheet shows? Why make stuff more complex? Is there something I may have missed here?

Comment: @Andyaka  If I want to use the above complete circuit, both the biasing circuitry and power amplifier circuitry should be on the same PCB. We are designing separate PCB for biasing circuitry and power amplifier circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

In principle I think you could but given that the title of the AN contains the word 'fail-safe' and GaNs are horribly frail and fry just looking at them I don't know if it would be wise… I think that if you need to ask the question you shouldn't mess with such a critical circuit. I mean, there are big red words in the text too:D